# IndexOutOfRangeException while adding text to String

Tags: c#, arrays, string

My programs adds two arrays into a part of a string using a while loop
ex:

```
hnames[0] = user
hvals[0] = admin
```

transformed into: user=admin&

I get IndexOutOfRangeException and i don't know how to fix it.

```
string[] hnames = names.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
string[] hvals = values.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
String postData = "";
//Loops through the arrays and put data into postData var
while (i < hnames.Length)
{
    i++;
    int end = hnames.Length;
    end--;
    if (!(i == end))
    {
        postData = postData + hnames[i] + "=" + hvals[i] + "&"; //IndexOutOfRangeException here
    }
    else
    {
        postData = postData + hnames[i] + "=" + hvals[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your arrays of the same length?

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? It's a really trivial problem.

Comment: I did, but didn't find where it was coming from even if it was a very simple error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` before using it, so at the end of the loop, when `i = hnames.Length - 1`, the `i++;` at the start of the loop sets `i = hnames.Length`, which is over the end of the array. You're also skipping `i = 0`, in effect.

Move `i++;` down to the end of the loop.

Comment: This is why programmers invented `foreach`.http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: Yes, `for` and `foreach` loops are a more orthodox way of doing stuff such.

Comment: This assumes that both arrays are of same length

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to show you a simplified version of your logic with the `foreach` as suggested by others. Number of lines may be same but I think this is easy to read.

```
        string[] hnames = names.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
        string[] hvals = values.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];

        string postData = string.Empty;
        bool isFirst = true;
        int i = 0;

        /* Assumption - Both arrays hnames and hvals are of same length.
                        Otherwise you'll get the same error if hvals.Length < hnames.Length even if you use the foreach
         */
        foreach (string hname in hnames)
        {
            if (isFirst)
            {
                postData = hname + "=" + hvals[i] + "&"; //IndexOutOfRangeException here
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                postData += hname + "=" + hvals[i];
            }

            i++;
        }
```